# Ho can I copy files from mutible pcs to network share and create a folder?

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I need to copy 10 .ini files from various locations on a pc to a network share. I need to run this against 500 computers. The below code works great but the issue is they have the same name on each computer and this puts all the files in the one folder.

Can anyone tell me how I can add extra locations to the below code and to create a new folder based on the name in list.txt eg branch01, branch02 etc and have all the ini files from branch01 copy to \networkshare\branch01.

```
Get-Content list.txt | ForEach-Object {
if(Test-Connection $_ -Quiet -Count 1){

Copy-Item "\\$_\c$\windows\test.ini" "\\Networkshare\Branch01"
```

Comment: Does your destination really have shares `Branch01`, `Branch02`, ...? Or are they subfolders of the actual share (i.e. `\\host\share\Branch01`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$branch = 1

Get-Content list.txt | ForEach-Object {
    if(Test-Connection $_ -Quiet -Count 1){
        $branch2 = $branch.ToString()
        $folder = $_ + $branch2
        Copy-Item "\\$_\c$\windows\*.ini" "\\Networkshare\$folder"
    }

    $branch = $branch + 1
}
```

The way I understand your question, that should solve your problem.

**EDIT: Look at this:**

```
PS C:\> $v1 = "hello"
PS C:\> $v2 = "world"
PS C:\> $v3 = $v1 + $v2
PS C:\> echo $v3
hello world
```

**EDIT 2: Look at the String conversion**

Comment: Thanks for that Ill test now.
Do you know how I can add more ini files for example 
C:\wpcc\wpcc.ini and C:\program files\folder1\dummy.ini

Comment: Just add the following lines: `Copy-Item "C:\wpcc\wpcc.ini" "\\Networkshare\$folder"` and `Copy-Item "C:\program files\folder1\dummy.ini" "\\Networkshare\$folder"`